# How to query DBpedia

Tags: php, sparql, dbpedia

I am trying send a query to DBpedia's endpoint http://dbpedia.org/sparql via a php script, with no succes unfortunately. This is the script:

```
<?php
require_once('sparqllib.php');
$db = sparql_connect('http://dbpedia.org/sparql');
$query = "SELECT ?film
WHERE { ?film <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:French_films> }";

$result = sparql_query($query);
$fields = sparql_field_array($result);
while($row = sparql_fetch_array($result))
{
  foreach($fileds as $field)
  {
    print"$row[$field] \n";
  }
}
?>
```

It gives me an HTTP 500 error.

UPDATE:

I really need help, please! I tried everything I know, with no succes. The curios thing is that in Python, a similar script works... I am really frustrated about this.

Comment: Although the [500 Internal Server Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is “[a] generic error message, given when no more specific message is suitable,” do you happen to get any text description with the response?  Your query is well-formed, and running it at the [public endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) works just fine.  I'm not much of a PHP user, so this may be a basic question, but why is the query quoted with single quotes and double quotes (i.e., the `'" ... "'`)?

Comment: Yes, I haven't seen that mistake. However, this is not the cause of my problem... I still get the same error.

Comment: What about the first question I asked?  Is there any text description with the response?  It's unlikely that someone will be able to answer without more information.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you try to run the query using the other interfaces that [`sparqllib.php`](http://graphite.ecs.soton.ac.uk/sparqllib/) provides?  E.g., if you use `sparql_get`, which takes the endpoint URL and the query in the same function call, do you still get the problem?  How about the object interface  (`$db = sparql_connect(…); $sparql = "…"; $result = $db->query( $sparql );`)?

Comment: Can you run a simpler query successfully?  E.g., `SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 5`?

Comment: I found my mistake. I wrote fileds instead of fields, the code was ok. Thank for the help

Comment: The fields/fileds code wouldn't cause an HTTP 500 error though.  Did you find out the problem with the SPARQL query?  And if you did, could you post it as an answer (and accept) so that others can benefit from your experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*From the comments on the question:*

> I found my mistake. I wrote fileds instead of fields, the code was ok. Thank for the help – Vali Voicu